# Have any planets been discovered in Orion constellation?

Tags: exoplanet, constellations, orion

Orion constellation is a very famous constellation. It can be seen throughout the earth. Orion looks like a warrior with a weapon and skirt. I see this constellation daily and wonder, if there is a planet there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are  exo-planets discovered in the Orion constellation, for instance, the stars [HD 37605](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_37605_b) and [HD 38529](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_38529) both have two known planets.

[HD 38858](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_38858) is also interesting, as it has a known planet, and also a disk of comets.

[image: HD 38858]

Comment: Any of them earthlike? I mean which could support life 

Comment: Well, HD 38858b is within the habitable zone, but it is 32 Earth masses. Small planets like Earth are incredibly difficult to detect.

Comment: @Rishabh Sharma- What made you wonder about if Orion contained a  planet similar to Earth and contained life like Earth as well?

Comment: @Rishabh Sharma-You're also honest- that's good.but you are looking in the right direction. The Orion constellation is my favorite also.Hope that link helped you.

Comment: @ The Void - that helped me too.. Voted it up

Comment: @Rishabh Sharma: Nothing we know of today could support life, except for Earth. 'Habitability' is a scientific nonsense-word.

Answer (score 2):

(RV)-discovered planet around HD 38858,
and then RV limits on undiscovered planets around HD 20794,
61 Vir (HD 115617), HD 69830, and HD 38858.

http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~wyatt/kmmg15.pdf